# Using a CP2102 USB-Breakout to Program an ESP8266 on an NodeMCU v1

Tags: arduino, uart, esp8266

I have a NodeMCU board with a broken UART module. So I tried to program the esp8266 via an external CP2102 breakout board. I have powered the NodeMCU directly with 3.3V on the 3.3V pin and connected TX/RX/GND of the CP2102 breakout board.

I am able to receive the "ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)" via the serial monitor of the arduino ide. But I just get an error when I try to program the esp826 with the arduino ide:

> warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed error:
>   espcomm_upload_mem failed error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

What I am doing wrong? I am pressing Flash, tap reset and release the flash button on the nodemcu board.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering the esp8266 directly from the 3.3v pin of the CP2102 board, this one doesn't has the enough current (>200mA) to run the esp8266. You must to connect the esp8266 to an external 3.3V power supply which should  give more than 400mA.

Comment: I am using an external power source for 3.3V

Comment: Which baud rate are you using it?